# user profile issue with Forms Authentication and SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication, user-profile

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am using publishing portal. And I am using a custom Forms authentication solution -- I store user name and password in a custom (schema) SQL Server database. The database stores user profile information. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SharePoint Server 2007 SDK.

I want to learn how to program to integrate the user profile stored in database into SharePoint user profile management (so that from SharePoint all users information, I can click a link for a user and then the profile data stored in my database could be displayed)? Any feasible solution? Appreciate if some code samples which could be referred.

BTW: I just care the same value of profile be displayed, no need to retrieve user profile data from my custom database, any other repository is ok.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement an ASP.NET Membership Provider. Basically you'll inherit from `ProviderBase` and to implement methods which will know to transform your custom schema in useful information for Sharepoint environment. This link can help: [Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

I suggest you to develop that custom provider in a regular ASP.NET site and, when you done, to install it at Sharepoint website.

**EDIT:** Take a look into this article series: [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx). It's very complete.

Comment: I know there is all users list information from SharePoint, and how could SharePoint get all user information from the membership provider I implemented?

Comment: Sharepoint will to use that membership specific methods to get your users information

Comment: I saw the MSDN page you mentioned, any sample implementation? Better if tailored for SharePoint. :-)

Comment: Membership isn't specific to Sharepoint. Build a sample which works with ASP.net ans, later, configure your Sharepoint by editing its web.config.

Comment: I know how to implement membership and profile provider, but how to let SharePoint use the profile provider I developed?

Comment: @George2, did you made that provider work in a ASP.NET site? You'll need to do _same_ changes in your Sharepoint site config file.